# JSON Post from a Webhook is null when type is string

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, webhooks

I am using .NET 5 web api. I have a webhook that posts to my api. However, When I receive the POST in a string it is null. If I create a class, then .Net will parse the JSON for me, but I **need** a string, not an object. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Example of JSON POST (application/json; charset=UTF-8):

```
{
    "user_ip": "00.00.00.00",
    "date_start": "2022-01-01T14:05:27.546Z",
    "user_referrer": "N/A",
    "user_os": "Windows (deprecated)",
    "id": "000001",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "position": 2,
            "value": "01/01/2022"
        },
        {
            "id": "0",
            "position": 8,
            "value": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "position": 22,
            "value": "7843377133"
        },
        {
            "values": [
                {
                    "position": 2,
                    "value": "Coffee"
                },
                {
                    "position": 5,
                    "value": "Tea"
                }
            ],
            "id": "14",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "position": 8,
            "value": "This is a test for API"
        }
    ],
    "user_device": "Desktop"
}
```

Endpoint - `val` is null when type string:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/webhooks/[controller]")]
    public class FormController : BaseApiController
    {
       
        [HttpPost("Form")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Form([FromBody] string val)
        {

           
            FormDataModel FS = new FormDataModel(){

                ResultJsonString = val  
               
            };

             return Ok(new {Data = FS});

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only use JObject input parameter for example and convert it to json using ToString()

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Form([FromBody] JObject val)
{
          ResultJsonString = val.ToString();
         .... another code  
}
```

another way is to serialize twice before POST to API, in this case you can get a string as val, but it is very bad coding style.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a template object to deserialize the json, and then you can access the string as a member of the object created. i. e.

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/webhooks/[controller]")]
    public class FormController : BaseApiController
    {
       
        [HttpPost("Form")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Form([FromBody] CustomObject val)
        {

           
            FormDataModel FS = new FormDataModel(){

                ResultJsonString = val.items[0].value 
                //or whatever path it is to the string you're interested in
               
            };

             return Ok(new {Data = FS});

        }
```

Comment: I need all of the Json string not just the array of items.

Comment: @Jet813 as in the entire JSON response represented as a string?

Comment: That is correct.